# R.id-Error "constant expression required"

Tags: java, android-studio, r.id

new to this I wanted to create a small quiz app with android studio. getting error in my switch/case while trying to give the buttons their function. the error is "constant expression required"

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonCheck:
               if(etLogoName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(companyName)){
                    currentLevel ++;
                    safeLevel();
                    loadLevel();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Leider falsch",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonHint:
                tvHint.setText("Erster Buchstabe" + companyName.substring(0, 1));
                tvHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSkip:
                currentLevel++;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lösung: " + companyName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loadLevel();

                break;


        }


<Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Hinweis"/>
```

tried rebuilding the project, deleting gradle cache, looking if a wrong R-class was implemented, checked XML-code, asked chatGPT for help :D

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: `R.id` values used to be final, but starting with Android Gradle Plugin version 8.0.0 they are no longer final and therefore no longer count as "constant expressions". Either add the flag as in the linked answer or change from `switch / case` to `if - else if` chains.